# Water softener with a 2 inch main line

Tags: water-softener

I am looking to install a water softener for my home. The main line into the home is 2 inch which branches off to 1 inch eventually for hot and cold water and then to the fixtures. My question is, if I get a 1 inch water softener installed at the main line, how much pressure loss am i going to see? The softened water would now go  back into a 2 inch pipe which will again get distributed to 1 inch pipes.

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

2" inlet water softeners aren't commonly available, so they'll probably be expensive. Install a 1.25" or 1.5" inlet water softener and you'll be fine for a typical 3 story 6-8 person household.

Comment: Thank you @Dotes. We ended up going with a company that installed a 1.25 inch system. It has been fine so far with no noticeable pressure loss.